# Unable to login after Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install

Tags: 18.04, login, nvidia-geforce, display-manager

I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04 .iso file and installed it. When booting the first time it asked me for my password, but when I entered the password at the login screen it rejected it three times and after that accepted my password. Then I saw a mouse pointer on the screen. After that I saw the default desktop wallpaper, and then it came back to the login screen.

I have an Nvidia GeForce 6150 SE 430 Nforce graphics card. Linux Mint didn't have the same problem, but Ubuntu 18.04 always has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the login display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. LightDM is a more lightweight login display manager than gdm3. In some Linux Mint releases lightdm is the default login display manager, and since Linux Mint does not have this login problem and Ubuntu 18.04 does, I suggest that you try using lightdm in Ubuntu 18.04.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install lightdm   
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm 
sudo reboot
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` will open up a new window allowing you to select lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select lightdm, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to put the focus on **<OK>** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot by running this command: `sudo reboot`